# Android native sip sdk - The client is in a transaction and cannot initiate a new one

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to create a SIP calling application based on Android native SIP SDK.

I have created the registration part as it is described in SipDemo application:

```
    public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (sipManager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (sipProfile != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    String username = "xxx";
    String domain = "xxx";
    String password = xxx;

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        builder.setDisplayName(username);
        builder.setProfileName(username);
        builder.setPort(5060);
        builder.setProtocol("UDP");
        builder.setOutboundProxy(domain);
        sipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        sipManager.open(sipProfile, pi, null);


        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

        sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registering with SIP Server ---> " + localProfileUri);
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ready ---> " + localProfileUri + " Expires ---> " + expiryTime);
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registration failed ---> " + errorMessage + " --- " + errorCode);
                }
            });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d(TAG,"ParseException. ", pe);
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.d(TAG,"SipException. ", se);
    }
}
```

It seems to work this way, but when I register a SIP account in my default calling application and after that try to register my own application with this method, the registration fails with the following message **"The client is in a transaction and cannot initiate a new one."**
Does this mean that I cannot use my local SIP application if I have set up a "global" SIP account in the default calling app?

Comment: have you resolved your issue ?

Comment: @Herry, no I was not able to solve this and I didn't try much as the native sip stack does not supported external codecs like G.729 and so on... Actually I ended up with buying a commercial SIP SDK for my app. But that is because my app is also commercial. In case if your app is not, you can try to use project called CSipSimple.. it is open source under GNU 2 license and is one of the best SIP stacks for Android platform.

Comment: @Andranik what commercial SIP SDK did you bought ?!!

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat I have bought  "abto voip sip sdk"